# angular 7 can't import mat-menu

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to use `mat-menu` in my `Angular` app. I'm getting the error

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "insertGMenu" (" Insert
>                       ]#insertMenu="insertGMenu" xPosition="after" yPosition="below">

Here is the component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="secondary">
             <mat-toolbar-row>
                    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="insertMenu">Insert</button>
                    <mat-menu #insertMenu="insertGMenu" xPosition="after" yPosition="below">
                      <button mat-menu-item>Portfolio</button>
                      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
                    </mat-menu>
              </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'gantt-toolbar',
    templateUrl: './ganttToolBar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ganttToolBar.component.css']
  })


export class GanttToolBar{

    constructor(){

    }
}
```

app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { GanttComponent } from './gantt/gantt.component';
import { GanttToolBar } from './gantt/ganttToolBar/ganttToolBar.component';
import { GanttPropertyService} from './services/gantt/ganttPropertyService';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    GanttComponent,
    GanttToolBar,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule, BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [GanttPropertyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.json

`{
  "name": "lp-scheduler-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "dhtmlx-gantt": "file:scripts/thirdParty/dhtmlxGantt",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}`

I've looked at other questions on SO but none of the solutions work.

Things I've tried

-reinstalling dependencies
-upgrading dependencies
-exporting MatMenuModule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
<mat-menu #insertMenu="insertGMenu" xPosition="after" yPosition="below">
```

to

```
<mat-menu #insertMenu="matMenu" xPosition="after" yPosition="below">
```

In the official doc described that selector **mat-menu** is exported as **matMenu**
You can check it here https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api

Comment: Thanks, I've deleted my answer and have accepted yours.